# UI Components and Canvas Context

Tags: html, user-interface, canvas

Is it possible to draw HTML UI Components onto a Canvas (2D) context ?

I would like to render, buttons, listboxes, text input controls onto a 2D Canvas Context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible using standard HTML elements. The `canvas` element is only used to render raster images. You can however emulate this behavior using canvas, but then you are required to keep track of everything such as the mouse position, states and events.